# Proper way to use `RequirePackage` and avoid option clash

Tags: package-writing, package-options

I'm developing a small LaTeX library that requires hyperref to work, but I'm facing 2 problems:

1. I think that hyperref should usually be loaded at the very end. However, if I put a `\RequirePackage{hyperref}` in my library, will it be loaded at the beginning? If the user also adds `\usepackage{hyperref}` at the end, will it solve the problem, or will it be ignored as `hyperref` was already loaded before?
2. When the user adds options to the `hyperref` package, it breaks with an error:

   ERROR: LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref.

So what is the proper way to say "my package requires hyperref", but still allow the user to overwrite the hyperref options/make sure it's loaded last?

Thanks!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mypackage.sty}
  \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
  \ProvidesPackage{mypackage}[2020/07/13 A dummy package]
  \RequirePackage{hyperref}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\usepackage{mypackage}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is ultimately a limitation of LaTeX. You may find this helpful: http://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-optionclash

Comment: You could leave it to the user to load `hyperref` and say in the documentation of your package **please load hyperref**  but use `\PassOptionsToPackage{<option list>}{hyperref}` in your package file. See the [`clsguide`](https://ctan.org/pkg/clsguide) for more help on package and class creation

Comment: There is no proper way, loading hyperref is currently a bit of a pain. (But we hope to improve this). You can try `\AtEndPreamble{\RequirePackage{hyperref}`  (needs etoolbox), but it doesn't solve every problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Option Clash error only happens when the options used at the second `\usepackage` are not empty and differ from the first option list, so you can defer loading `hyperref` at the very end of the preamble (for example, by using `etoolbox`'s `\AtEndPreamble`) and load it without options.  In this case, if the user doesn't load `hyperref`, your package does at the end of the preamble.  If the user *does* load `hyperref` with options, then your `\RequirePackage{hyperref}` line won't raise an error because no option was requested.  You can pass options to hyperref using `\PassOptionsToPackage{hidelinks}{hyperref}`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mypackage.sty}
  \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
  \ProvidesPackage{mypackage}[2020/07/13 A dummy package]
  \RequirePackage{etoolbox}
  % Any option your package wants:
  % \PassOptionsToPackage{hidelinks}{hyperref}
  \AtEndPreamble{%
    \RequirePackage{hyperref}}%
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\usepackage{mypackage}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

But this will be problematic, for example, with `cleveref`, or other packages that must be loaded after `hyperref`: the user will *have to* load `hyperref` explicitly before loading `cleveref`, otherwise things won't work properly.